# J2ME, Exception when casting from PemObject to AsymmetricKeyParameter with BouncyCastle

Tags: encryption, java-me, casting, bouncycastle

my question for today is about the BouncyCastle encryption Library for J2ME,
I have some code in C# in which I do the following cast:

`AsymmetricKeyParameter pubKey = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)pubReader.ReadObject();`

this works on the C# end, however when I do it in Java I get an error stating that pubReader doesn't have a ReadObject() method, I changed it to readObject(), still doesn't exist so I went ahead to search for a method that would return an Object type, I only found readPemObject() as follows:

`AsymmetricKeyParameter pubKey = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)pubReader.readPemObject();`

However... this is when I hit the big problem, as I cannot cast from PemObject to AsymmetricKeyParameter and end up having an error...

here's the majority of the code in question:

```
PemReader pubReader = new PemReader(new StringReader(pubKey));      
AsymmetricKeyParameter nhe = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)pubReader.readPemObject();

Imported teste = new Imported();        
PemObject pobj = pubReader.readPemObject();

System.out.println("PemObject: " + pobj);
byte[] output = teste.Encrypt(holyshizzle.getBytes(), nhe);
System.out.println(new String(output));         
byte[] revvit = teste.Decrypt(output, (AsymmetricKeyParameter)blah.getPrivate());
System.out.println(new String(revvit));`
```

PS: The Imported class is where the encrypt/decrypt code is and all of that is working fine (tested it with generated keys), I'm attempting to do this with pre-made encryption keys

Regards,
Gonçalo Vieira

Comment: The equivalent function is in the `org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMReader` class. This class is only available in the full Bouncycastle provider library, not in the J2ME version. Are you only interested in RSA keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing

```
AsymmetricKeyParameter nhe = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)pubReader.readPemObject();
```

with

```
AsymmetricKeyParameter nhe = PublicKeyFactory.createKey(pubReader.readPemObject().getContent());
```